# How to search many sheets?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have one main Google spreadsheet that has many sheets inside it, I am using a google script to search for specific data using name/password but I need to apply the search on all sheets in this main spreadsheet, please help me how to figure this out :

```js
var sheetName = "Data"
  
var range = SpreadsheetApp.openById(spreadsheetId).getSheetByName(sheetName).getDataRange();
var data = range.getValues();
var ar = [];
```

Answer (score 2):

I believe your goal as follows.

- You want to search a text from all sheets in a Google Spreadsheet.

In this case, I would like to propose to use TextFinder. When TextFinder is used, the text can be searched from all sheets in a Google Spreadsheet. The sample script is as follows.

#### Sample script:

```js
function myFunction() {
  const spreadsheetId = "###"; // Please set Spreadsheet ID.
  const searchText = "sample"; // Please set the seatch text.

  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(spreadsheetId);
  const ranges = ss.createTextFinder(searchText).matchEntireCell(true).findAll();
  const res = ranges.map(r => ({sheet: r.getSheet().getSheetName(), range: r.getA1Notation()}));
  console.log(res)
}
```

- When this script is run, the list of the sheet name and a1Notation is returned. About this, please modify it for your actual situation.

#### References:

- [createTextFinder(findText) of Class Spreadsheet](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#createTextFinder(String))
- [Class TextFinder](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/text-finder)

Comment: Thanks a lot, but I am using the script to look for two things: password and name from a user and then show relevant info, my problem is that I would like to make the search for all sheets in my Google spreadsheet but I am stuck with : var sheetName = "Data"

I am looking for the correct code to make the search for all sheets?

Comment: @ahsan Thank you for replying. About `my problem is that I would like to make the search for all sheets in my Google spreadsheet`, my proposed script searches the search text from all sheets of the Spreadsheet. Is that the same direction you expect?

Comment: No,  my script takes an input from a user (ID/Password) and runs over the sheet (Data) and grabs info to show to the user. The script only works using getSheetByName() but Does NOT work when I try to search all sheets in my spreadsheet (Data, Data1, Data2, Data3 ..etc)
I tried using .getSheets but it does not work!

Comment: @ahsan Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill. In my proposed script, the text is searched from all sheets of Google Spreadsheet. When I saw your reply, it seems that the action is the same as my proposed script. So, unfortunately, I cannot understand `but Does NOT work when I try to search all sheets in my spreadsheet (Data, Data1, Data2, Data3 ..etc) I tried using .getSheets but it does not work!`. Can I ask you about the detail of your current issue?

Comment: I am truly grateful for your help, I have a google spreadsheet and inside there are many sheets (Data, Data2, Data3 ..etc). I want to setup a web page that will let my students search for their grades and read my feedback which should only be visible to that particular student.

Comment: @ahsan I have to apologize for my poor English skill again. In my proposed answer, a text can be searched from all sheets in a Google Spreadsheet. This is from How to search many sheets?. Can I ask you about the difference between my understanding and your goal? If you can do, can you provide the sample value of your search text? And can you provide the sample output situation you expect? And can you provide the detail of it does not work!? I would like to correctly understand the issue of my proposed answer. If my answer has the issue, I would like to modify it.

Comment: OK,
here's a link to my code: 
https://abnaa.notion.site/Google-Script-cd2ea22e25f140149699c92759fd6d5f

I need to expand the search range to include all sheets

Comment: @ahsan Thank you for replying. From your question and your sample script, I understood that you wanted to search for text from all sheets of a Spreadsheet. For this, I proposed an answer. But, when I saw your [link](https://abnaa.notion.site/Google-Script-cd2ea22e25f140149699c92759fd6d5f), I think that your current question is different from your initial question. So, I would like to propose posting it as a new question by including more information.